# NSLayoutConstraint in UICollectionViewCell: Size Class Customization doesn't work

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to customize size of the image inside my UICollectionViewCell,
but I haven't managed to achieve the result yet.

here is my cell

[image]

and here is inspector for the height constraint

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

I've just noticed some logs

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78fcab10 V:[UIImageView:0x78fcaa00(129)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78fcb100 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x78fcaa00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x78fca940 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78fcb130 V:[UILabel:0x78fcac40'Completed all MEDIUM quiz...']-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x78fca940 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78fcb190 V:[UIImageView:0x78fcaa00]-(8)-[UILabel:0x78fcac40'Completed all MEDIUM quiz...']>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x79195380 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x78fca940(50)]>"
)
```

But I do not understand how NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint appears here.

Comment: Could you provide some info on what it is doing? Are there any layout constraint errors logged?

Comment: @JoGoFo Thanks, didn't notice a log message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot:

1. you aligned image horizontally and added leading constraint. remove it, if you want to have fixed image size.
2. if you want your view to automatically resize image (by width) - remove width constraint & horizontal align and add trailing constraint.

It depends on goal.

Hope this helps

Comment: 1. It is grater than or equal relation

Comment: @BergP, from you screenshot - it's not. it would have '=>' symbol near constraint

Comment: 2. I need to resize it by constraint, because label could contains 2 lines, In this case images in collection view would have different sizes.

Comment: @BergP,1. remove height constraint from image view. 2. set greater than or equal height for label. 3. pin in to bottom of superview. 4. add bottom constraint for image (to this label). 5. remove height constraint for image

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but in this case I cannot add greater than or equal constraint for label. Because it should have different font size for iPad, that return us to the original question :) I need to make size class customization for the height constraint of label.

Comment: and how does font size break your autolayout model? label will automatically resize depend on your's label content

Comment: 2. set greater than or equal height for label. - the constant of height constraint should be twice bigger than the font. So I need to set 2 different constants for label's height.

Comment: why it should be twice bigger? it's unnecessary. it will automatically resize regardless of the font size. set constant value to 0. or, finally, use size classes to handle this problem (set different constant values for ipad and iphone devices) http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial